# Why Leray-Hirsch theorem does not state a ring isomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let us take a fiber bundle $p: E\rightarrow B$ with a fiber $F$ whose cohomology is freely generated, and there is $\{c_i\in H^*(E;R)\}$ which is a basis when restricted to each fiber. Under such conditions, Leray-Hirsch theorem states the following module isomorphism:
\begin{eqnarray}
H^*(B;R)\otimes_R H^*(F;R)\cong H^*(E;R),
\end{eqnarray}
by
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i,j} b_i\otimes i^*(c_j)\mapsto \sum_{i,j} p^*(b_i)\cup c_j,
\end{eqnarray}
where $i:F\rightarrow E$ is an inclusion of a fiber into $E$.

I have difficulty in seeing that the above isomorphism is not a ring isomorphism. Why can't we just define a multiplication in the tensor product of the graded rings $H^*(B;R)\otimes_R H^*(F;R)$ by:
\begin{eqnarray}
(a\otimes b)(c\otimes d)\equiv (-1)^{|b||c|}(a\cup c)\otimes (b\cup d),
\end{eqnarray}
where $a\in H^{|a|}(B;R)$ etc., and then prove the above isomorphism is consistent with this ring multiplication, i.e., a ring isomorphism (just like in Kunneth formula)?

Comment: I have found the potential problem as follows: when we try to "prove" the ring homomorphism, we need to show $i^*(c_m\cup c_n)$ is mapped to $c_m\cup c_n$ which is however not necessarily true. It is because when we denote $i^*(c_m\cup c_n)\equiv \sum_jL^j_{mn}i^*(c_j)$, $i^*(c_m\cup c_n)$ is actually mapped to $\sum_jL^j_{mn}c_j$. Therefore, I guess that we need much more extra, e.g., $i^*$ is injective like the bundle is trivial, to ensure a ring homomorphism in general.

Comment: Yeah, while from the base you lift your elements "geometrically", from the fiber is comes by means of an $additive$ section of $i^*$.

Comment: Consider the fibration $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^3\rightarrow S^4$ to note the fail of the isomorphism to be one of rings.